# How to replace the Laravel Builder class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to replace the Laravels builder class with my own that's extending from it. I thought it would be as simple as matter of `App::bind` but it seems that does not work. Where should I place the binding and what is the proper way to do that in Laravel?

This is what I have tried:

my **Builder**:

```
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder as BaseBuilder;
    class Builder  extends  BaseBuilder
    {

        /**
         * Find a model by its primary key.
         *
         * @param  mixed  $id
         * @param  array  $columns
         * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|static|null
         */
        public function find($id, $columns = array('*'))
        {
            Event::fire('before.find', array($this));
            $result = parent::find($id, $columns);
            Event::fire('after.find', array($this));
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

And next I tried to register the binding in bootstrap/start.php file like this :

```
$app->bind('Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder', 'MyNameSpace\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder');
return $app;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` class is an internal class and as such it is not dependency injected into the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class, but kind of hard coded there.

To do what you want to do, I would extend the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` to `MyNamespace\Database\Eloquent\Model` class and override `newEloquentBuilder` function.

```
public function newEloquentBuilder($query)
{
   return new MyNamespace\Database\Eloquent\Builder($query);
}
```

Then alias `MyNamespace\Database\Eloquent\Model` to `Eloquent` at the `aliases` in `app/config/app.php`

Answer (score 5):

Both of the answers are correct in some way. You have to decide what your goal is.

**Change Eloquent Builder**

For example, if you want to add a new method only for eloquent models (eg. something like scopes, but maybe a little more advanced so it’s not possible in a scope)

Create a new Class extending the Eloquent Builder, for Example CustomEloquentBuilder.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;


class CustomEloquentBuilder extends Builder 
{

    public function myMethod()
    {
        // some method things
    }

}
```

Create a Custom Model and overwrite the method *newEloquentBuilder*

```
use Namespace\Of\CustomEloquentBuilder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class CustomModel extends Model
{

    public function newEloquentBuilder($query)
    {
        return new CustomEloquentBuilder($query);
    }

}
```

**Change Database Query Builder**

For example to modify the where-clause for all database accesses

Create a new Class extending the Database Builder, for Example CustomQueryBuilder.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;


class CustomQueryBuilder extends Builder 
{

    public function myMethod()
    {
        // some method things
    }

}
```

Create a Custom Model and overwrite the method *newBaseQueryBuilder*

```
use Namespace\Of\CustomQueryBuilder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class CustomModel extends Model
{

    protected function newBaseQueryBuilder()
    {
        $connection = $this->getConnection();

        return new CustomQueryBuilder(
            $connection, $connection->getQueryGrammar(), $connection->getPostProcessor()
        );
    }

}
```

Laravel Version: 5.5 / this code is untestet

Answer (score 4):

The answer above doesn't exactly work for laravel > 5 so I done some digging and I found this!

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1868

use this instead!

```
protected function newBaseQueryBuilder()
{
    $conn = $this->getConnection();
    $grammar = $conn->getQueryGrammar();
    return new QueryBuilder($conn, $grammar, $conn->getPostProcessor());
}
```