# how to extend Builder class in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, eloquent, builder

I tried to extend Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder to override various functions, but i cant make it.

I created a custom builder (CustomBuilder.php)

```
<?php
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\ConnectionInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\Processor;

class CustomBuilder extends Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder {

    public function get($columns = ['*'])
    {
        $builder = $this->applyScopes();

        $models = $builder->getModels($columns);

        if (count($models) > 0) {
            $models = $builder->eagerLoadRelations($models);
        }

        return $builder->getModel()->newCollection($models);
    }
}
```

And a custom model (CustomModel.php)

```
<?php
use DateTime;
use ArrayAccess;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use LogicException;
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo;
use Illuminate\Support\Contracts\JsonableInterface;
use Illuminate\Support\Contracts\ArrayableInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphOne;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
// use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder as QueryBuilder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasManyThrough;
use Illuminate\Database\ConnectionResolverInterface as Resolver;
use CustomBuilder as QueryBuilder; // MyModel should now use your MyQueryBuilder instead of the default which I commented out above

abstract class CustomModel extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{

}
?>
```

What is the correct folder to put these files, and how to call it from my models?

I tried in app/Extensions, in vendor, but i get the same error.
Class CustomModel cannot be found.

Thanks

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23475300/how-to-replace-the-laravel-builder-class

Comment: yes, i created my class in vendor/customlaravel/Database/Eloquent, and changed in app.php.
Now how to call it from the model? With "Eloquent\CustomModel"?
Thanks

Comment: You need to override `function newBaseQueryBuilder()` on the model. Returning something like: `return new CustomBuilder()`

Comment: thanks, but the problem is that i cannot access to my class.
I created my CustomModel inside vendor/customlaravel/src/CustomModel.php, and im trying to use:
use CustomLaravel\CustomModel.php, but i get the error
"Class CustomLaravel\CustomModel not found".

In my composer.json (vendor/customlaravel) i added this:
"psr-4": {"CustomLaravel\\": "src"}

is correct?

Comment: Why did you created your model on vendor folder?

Comment: I created CustomModel (to use CustomBuilder.php instead laravel Builder.php) in the vendor folder.
And my entity models in app folder
is not correct?