# Rename laravel collection "data" key

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, collections, eloquent, laravel-5.4

Is there way i can rename the data key in laravel collection results? At the moment this

```
DB::table('contracts AS C')->paginate(1)
```

returns

```js
  {
  "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 191,
            "buyer": "John",
            "provider": "Jane"
        }
    ],
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 1,
    "next_page_url": "",
    "path": "",
    "per_page": 1,
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "to": 1,
    "total": 1
}
```

What i would like is this

```js
  {
  "current_page": 1,
    "parties": [
        {
            "id": 191,
            "buyer": "John",
            "provider": "Jane"
        }
    ],
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 1,
    "next_page_url": "",
    "path": "",
    "per_page": 1,
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "to": 1,
    "total": 1
}
```

The challenge here changing the data key to parties

Comment: Have you solved this? I have the same problem

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [`keyBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-keyby) method of collection.

```
$unfiltered = DB::table('contracts AS C')->paginate(1);

$filtered = $unfiltered->keyBy(function ($value, $key) {
     if ($key == 'data') {
         return 'parties';
     } else {
         return $key;
     }
});

return $filtered;
```

Comment: This returns an empty object

Comment: it is not the desired result. The edited solution creates extra empty object along with the results.

Comment: @CengkuruMichael : If you'd want to alter the original collection keys, use the `keyBy` method instead

Answer (score 1):

You could just convert the collection to array and manipulate it:

```
$result = DB::table('contracts AS C')->paginate(1)->toArray();
$data = $result['data'];
unset($result['data']);
$result['parties'] = $data;

return $result;
```

This does not require any extra loops either.

Answer (score 0):

The `data` key is only set when the Paginator object `toArray()` is called. Before that it's a Collection with the key `items`.

Quick and dirty solution would be to call `toArray()` on the Paginator object and change the key name of the array before the `json_encode()`.

---

Another solution would be to extend the Builder class, much like [it's done here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23486732/1483117), overwrite the `paginate()` method and Paginator's `toArray()` method.

Answer (score 0):

you can return data with below code :

```
$coins = CoinResource::collection(Cryptocurrency::all());
return ['your_custom_name' => $coins];
```